# How to make a subpage in simple html?

Tags: html, web

I am making an internally used html site for my company. I am a beginner at html and have done this by using a template form W3school. The site will be used to look up different work procedures for internal use only and will run on our server (not on the internet).

In the main site (main.htm) I have a menu bar on the left with links to subpages (sub1.htm, sub2.htm and so on). As it is now I use iFrame to open the subpages in my main site. This way the entire site including the menu bar will stay and only the subpage will load when I change subpage. My issue is that I cannot go directly to a subpage by typing main.htm/sub5 or similar. I always have to start at the main.htm and then click the link to a certain subpage. If I open the specific subpage from the file sub5.htm it will open but without the menu bar as this is not included in the .htm code.

Is there a better way to make the subpages open on the main page?

Comment: Before this gets closed: Don't use iframes here at all. generate all HTML files to have navigation included. Or do it with backend language like PHP / Java, ...

Comment: Make separate pages and copy the navigation bar into each one. Next step: use a templating framework that allows you to include the navbar into each page without copy and pasting it everywhere. That could be Javascript, server side programming, or a static HTML generator.

Comment: @ cloned: The issue in including the navigation in all html files is that if I make a change in the nav bar I have to copy paste this change into EVERY other html and there is more than 30 subpages. I really want to avoid this. That's why I chose iframe. I have no idea how to use PHP or Java...



@ deceze: Do you have an example of using templating framework? I am a total noob at this and all I know of html is self-taught started this January...

Comment: Search for any “static site generator” that tickles your fancy. It should allow you to write things like `<include “nav.html”>` or something of that sort (this example is made up), and then generate plain .html files from this template which contains the same navbar HTML without having to copy and paste it.

Comment: @deceze: I have found nicepage.com and this seems to be a solution for me (at first glance). Thanks